# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets.datastructures'

Tags: websocket, uvicorn

I don't know how to fix this error on Ubuntu.
I'm trying to run a FastApi server using `uvicorn`

`uvicorn.run("api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=3100, reload=True, workers=10)`

I've tried `pip3 install websockets` :

```
Collecting websockets
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/86/cef054220bc080451fe9663ce7f99beda0599098241190b6b6dc1073ab92/websockets-10.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 5.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: websockets
Successfully installed websockets-8.1
```

I don't know what else needs to be installed

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 471, in load
    ws_protocol_class = import_from_string(WS_PROTOCOLS[self.ws])
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/auto.py", line 17, in <module>
    from uvicorn.protocols.websockets.websockets_impl import WebSocketProtocol
  File "/home/hafid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/websockets_impl.py", line 9, in <module>
    from websockets.datastructures import Headers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets.datastructures'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to update setuptools and pip

`pip3 install -U setuptools`

`pip3 install -U pip`

Answer (score 4):

To me, any of the two other answers work. I just upgrade websockets with:

```
pip install -U websockets
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i'm not sure why this happened but i'll atleast show you my workaround.

The best thing to do would be running:

> `pip uninstall websockets`

> `pip install websockets`

But for some reason this command could not uninstall it for me, so i did it manually.

Since u are in Ubuntu open this folder as root:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websocket`

Then u can manually download the files at [websockets current version files](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/#files)

In my case i noticed that in my old websockets folder i didn't have `websockets.datastructures` and also some other files such as the folders `legacy` and `extensions` so i just unzipped the whole library to the path cited above and it worked.